# Why `as` is giving null for nullable value types?

Tags: c#, .net

```
long? i = 10000;
int? s = i as int?;
```

Why is it giving me a null in `s` variable? I know that casting it using `int? s = (int?)i;` will work fine but why can't I use an `as` operator?

Comment: The `as` operator returns null if the expression is of a different type, it doesn't make any attempt to convert it. When you use `(int?)i` you're actually calling an explicit operator (not a cast) to convert the value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/as):

> The code is equivalent to the following expression except that the expression variable is evaluated only one time.
>
> `expression is type ? (type)expression : (type)null`

Since `i is int?` is false the `as` keyword will return `(int?)null`.

Comment: if I can use `as` in nullable value types but it will always returns null then why they are allowing it ?

Comment: You can use it for nullable values. Example: `var s = i as object;` doesn't return null because `int?` is an object. `int?` isn't a `long?` though.

Answer (score 3):

The types aren't equivalent and you get null, that is just how `as` works

However, you could just direct *Cast*

```
long? i = 10000;
var s = (int?)i;

// or even better make sure its *checked* 

var s = checked((int?)i);
```

**Why does this work?**

[C# Language Specification 11.6.1 Nullable Conversions](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-334.pdf)

> ...
>
> Evaluation of a nullable conversion based on an underlying conversion
> from S to T proceeds as follows:
>
> - If the *nullable* conversion is from `S?` to `T?`:
> - If the source value is null (`HasValue` property is `false`), the result is the `null` value of type `T?`.
> - Otherwise, the conversion is evaluated as an *unwrapping* from `S?` to `S`, followed by the underlying conversion from `S` to `T`, followed by a
>   wrapping from `T` to `T?`.
>
> ...

`as` does not do this, it checks the run-time types, if they are not equal returns null `T?`

---

**Additional Resources**

[checked (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked)

> The checked keyword is used to explicitly enable overflow checking for
> integral-type arithmetic operations and conversions.

#Update from comments

> I got that we can't convert and why we can't do I but why they are
> suggesting it is there any scenario where it will be useful i'e [some
> random image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8U1X.jpg) of [Compiler Error CS0077](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0077) *"The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type ('int' is a non-nullable value type)."*

The reason is (in your image example) a value type can't be null it could never work with it. The thing you are missing is there are more complex examples of what could happen, you can define *implicit* operators on custom types, etc.

Comment: if I can use `as` in nullable value types but it will always returns null then why they are allowing it ?

Comment: @avinash `as` doesn't work because it checks the checks the types

Comment: I got that we cant convert and why we can't do I but why they are suggesting it is there is any scenario where it will be useful [ss](https://imgur.com/a/jWrDlC5)

Comment: @avinash updated

Answer (score 0):

The compiler cannot implicitly convert 'long' to 'int'

And as per MSDN

> The as operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion
>   isn't possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception.

ref: [as (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/as)

So with your code, conversion is not possible, as is returning Null.

Comment: `long?` is not the same as `long` - you really can't apply `as` to value type conversions. So not clear how this applies to the question. (Let me know if you want me to downvote too in addition to comment - normally it is considered bad practice to do both due regular retaliation from authors of the posts)